# how to turn off web camera in IE using action script

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript-3, internet-explorer, webcam

I am using flash professional for take photo from webcam. My requirement is that I want to start camera and after 2 sec it will take photo and turn off the camera.

I did that and its working good in all browser except IE.
Actually, I am display:none that flash object after photo take, and it will automatically turn off camera in browser except IE.

If I display:none camera flash object, it will not turn off my webcam.

So, can you please help me in how to turn off web camera in IE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out.

I called action script function from java script.
In action script function I just pass null to attachCamera function like this way -  "video.attachCamera(null);"

null will turn off camera.

and its working in all browser.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working on me. The camera light remains on. I'm using Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect that to work well in all browsers (as you noticed). It would be better to send a function call to the flash file telling it to do whatever is needed to turn off the camera (deteach the camera from the screen I guess), using ExternalInterface.